# I have a error to pass my datta from blade file to Controller

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-8

This is my code in blade file :

```html
<form  action="{{ route('user.delete') }}" method="Delete" class="row g-3">
        @csrf
        <div class="col-auto">
            <select  class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Select User</option>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="1">{{$user->user_login}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-1">Delete User</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

And this is my fuction in Controller file :

```html
public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->get('user_login');
        $user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $username );
        wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
        return view('wp.user');
    }
```

How to take a value of Selected User in blade file to pass in my Function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  action="{{ route('user.delete') }}" method="POST" class="row g-3">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <div class="col-auto">
            <select  class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="user">
                <option selected>Select User</option>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="1">{{$user->user_login}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-1">Delete User</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

You are missing the name attribute `name="user"`, without name attribute it can't send the value on your case.

Comment: Added this attribute but dosen't work!!

Comment: I have updated the method as well, could you please copy the form and try again, I have changed `method="POST"` and added `@method('DELETE')`, also, could you please show your route? sometimes the route might be intercepted by some other matching route in the list and it might never reached the destination. you could confirm this by hitting `dd('hit')` on first line inside `delete` methods.

Comment: The data passed to my controller, but now i have this error " Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Wp\wp_delete_user()".

Comment: it looks like you are mixing WordPress with laravel, if `$user` returns the user object, you can delete user with `$user->delete()`. If this don't work, could you please paste `dd($user)`, just after `$user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $username );` and let me know what does it returns

Comment: it return false

Comment: okay, now instead of `dd($user)`, please do `dd($request->all())` and let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164319/insert-data-not-working-perfectly-in-laravel-8